# Connection with couchbase is getting hung

Tags: couchbase, telnet

I am trying to connect with couchbase like given below

> telnet 127.0.0.1 11210

I am getting connected also but when i am giving keyword "stats" it is getting hung there

```
root@vcb01-korakoram:~# telnet 127.0.0.1 11210
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
stats

^C
quit
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
```

for coming out I pressed 2-3 time "ctrl-C"

Tried to cnnect by using cbstats as given below:

```
root@vcb01-korakoram:~# /opt/couchbase/bin/cbstats 127.0.0.1:11210 all
Stats '' are not available from the requested engine. (Memcached error #36:  EACCESS : Not authorized for command : {"error":{"context":"An exception occurred. command: [STAT]","ref":"d6582c0d-a06a-411b-bc29-bfa758359a37"}})
```

but here it is showing this issue

Please let me know what is the issue.

Comment: Did you just start the server? It has a startup period where it loads data from disk- not sure if that’s what could be the trouble or if something else is messed up.

Comment: yes started the server